# Error: On adding of flutter_native_admob: ^2.1.0

Tags: flutter, admob

### Getting this error after using adding new dependency flutter_native_admob

```
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.zzd found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.1.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl:17.0.2)
```

Before adding this dependency and not implemeting admob native ads is working fine.
I also have added banne ads which is working fine but native creates problem.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution to this is, update all the dependencies in pubspec.yaml file to latest version...
Refer the link which i solved : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=askdb.com